# Using RSA in reverse to decrypt a licence code: encrypt with private key, decrypt with public key

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt some values pertaining to a licence code with a secret private key, and then when it's entered in the user's app install it will be decrypted with the public key (stored with the app) to view the encoded data and ensure it was only created by me.

The trouble is it seems that you encrypt with the *public* key and decrypt with the *private* key, which is the reverse of what I want.

It's also worth mentioning that the library I'm using called [`SwiftyRSA`](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) only supports encrypting with the public key, and doesn't like it when I use the private key instead. I believe this is because it's being saved to the keychain with `kSecAttrKeyClassPublic`, because that's what it's expecting, and that causes things to fail.

I have read that the keys are technically interchangeable, but it seems I can't get it to work in my instance. Is this because they public key has a smaller exponent? Is there a way to get the public key to be as "long" as the private key using `ssh-keygen`, and therefore be able to swap them around? If not, how could I proceed?

Comment: You should certainly be able to do this. What you are trying to create is a digital signature and it is used eveywhere; in fact when a certificate authority issues a certificate it signs (encrypts) information about the cert using their private key.  This allows the certificate to be verified if you know and trust their public key.

Comment: You need to use the crypto function `SecKeyRawSign` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyRawSign which that library doesn't expose.  The other thing you could do is just encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key; as long as the public key stays secret then no-one can generate a license code

Comment: @Paulw11 If I distribute the private key and keep the public key secret, can someone not just create the public key again from the private key like I originally did? And then they'd have the public key to generate a code. (I followed instructions in the [README](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/blob/master/README.md) of SwiftyRSA to create they key pair). Also, the public key is smaller than the private key, is that an issue security wise? Distributing a larger key and keeping the smaller one as the secret?

Comment: the private key is the same size as the public key, but he private key file includes more information and this information does, in fact, make it possible to recover the public key given the private key pem file. You can either take the risk that someone may attack your licensing system or you can use SwiftRSA as the basis of a framework that supports SecKeyRawSign

Comment: I have created a fork with digital signature support here - https://github.com/paulw11/SwiftyRSA I have also added a pull request to integrate this back into the main project.  To use it you really need to create an SHA1 digest of your data and sign that; I didn't build this function in because support of CommonCrypto in Swift frameworks is a bit tricky, but if you search on SO you will find some string extensions that generate SHA1 digests using Common Crypto

Comment: FYI version 0.3 of SwiftyRSA now includes my sign and verify additions

Answer (score 0):

The keys aren't always interchangeable (e.g. RSA private keys with CRT parameters) and it is pretty likely that the encryption procedure doesn't protect the key against side channel attacks. You should not use private keys to encrypt, period.

You could use signatures with message recovery if you're really careful.

Otherwise - if you've enough space - you could of course always sign-then-encrypt your license. For this to work (without additional AES encryption) your encryption key pair would have to be quite a bit larger than your signing key though.